# What is returning after executing command to extract mfcc?

Tags: python, librosa, mfcc, soundfile

I have been learning Sound Analysis and i have encountered term mfcc in it.
So when i execute 
`librosa.feature.mfcc(y=X, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=40)`
 I get numpy array of shape 40 by 216.
So i get that I have extracted 40 features over 216 frames.
But here what exactly is meant by frames , is it similar to sample rate and where we define it while loading the audio file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's not immediately obvious from the [mfcc docs](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.mfcc.html) is that it calls [librosa.feature.melspectrogram](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.melspectrogram.html) internally. And `melspectrogram` has the parameters `win_length`/`n_fft` and `hop_length`, which define a *frame*. You can also pass these parameters to `mfcc`.

So what's a frame? Basically, it's the result of processing a bunch of raw samples: Assuming a window length of 2048 samples (that's the default) and a hop length of 512 (also the default) each one of the frames returned by `mfcc` corresponds to 2048 raw samples and is 512 samples "further along in the audio" than its predecessor. In other words, there is a significant overlap between frames.

As an example, to create mfcc's for your audio, defining a frame as 1024 samples and a hop length of 512, you could call:

```
librosa.feature.mfcc(y=X, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=40, hop_length=512, n_fft=1024)
```

Again, if you are not explicitly passing those arguments, defaults from [melspectrogram](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.melspectrogram.html) are used.